# Why i get the notice "Undefined index" if they are in the url post

Tags: php, sql, database, forms

i get the Notice "Undefined index" but in the url I can see, that the fields are not empty. See yourself:

URL:

```
http://localhost/projektarbeit/version-03/send.php?vorname=asdf&name=asdf&strasse=asdf&hausnr=12&plz=12435&ort=asdf&email=asdf%40gmail.com
```

Notices:

```
Notice: Undefined index: vorname in C:\xampp\htdocs\projektarbeit\version-03\send.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\projektarbeit\version-03\send.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: strasse in C:\xampp\htdocs\projektarbeit\version-03\send.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: hausnr in C:\xampp\htdocs\projektarbeit\version-03\send.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: plz in C:\xampp\htdocs\projektarbeit\version-03\send.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: ort in C:\xampp\htdocs\projektarbeit\version-03\send.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\projektarbeit\version-03\send.php on line 11
```

Here's some code:

```
<form action="send.php" action="POST">
    <input type="text" name="vorname" pattern="{20}" required>
    <input type="text" name="name" pattern="{20}" required>
    <input type="text" name="strasse" pattern="{20}" required>
    <input type="text" name="hausnr" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+{5}" required>
    <input type="text" name="plz" pattern="[0-9]{5}" required>
    <input type="text" name="ort" pattern="{20}" required>
    <input type="email" name="email" required>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And my PHP-Script:

```
<?php
    include 'includes/db-connection.php';

    $vorname = $_POST['vorname'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $strasse = $_POST['strasse'];
    $hausnr = $_POST['hausnr'];
    $plz = $_POST['plz'];
    $ort = $_POST['ort'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
?>
```

Hope somebody can help me :s

Comment: You are using GET instead of POST. Read the documentation first, then ask.

Comment: I'm not wrong. But Dupuis isn't too. You showed an example of what happens with a `GET` url. You asked why the errors when everything was in the url. I answered that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to make a post submit is the use the `method` tag and not `action` tag.

Action contains your url : send.php and method : post

```
<form method="post" action="send.php">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using Get method as in the URL, query strings works for get requests. Use form method not action as POST.

Comment: *"Probably you are using Get method as in the URL"* - definitely not.